# execute commands sequentially in Promose/bluebird

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have an array that need to append to a database, the condition is, element has to be appended one after another to make it work, following is my code, seems commands are not executed sequentially, what's wrong with my code:thanks.

```
var B = require('bluebird')
var appends = []

recs.forEach(function (item) {
   appends.push(dao.append_rec_cartAsync(item))
})

B.all(appends).then(function () {
    console.log('all done')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `dao.append_rec_cartAsync(item)` you're *executing* the asynchronous operation. Once it's started you can't really do anything about it running. Also note that `Promise.all` does not do things sequentially but rather parallely.

```
var B = require('bluebird');
B.each(recs, function(item){ // note we use B.each and not forEach here
     // we return the promise so it knows it's done
     return dao.append_recs_cartAsync(item);
}).then(function(){
    console.log("all done!")
});
```

Or in short: `B.each(recs, dao.append_recs_cartAsync)`

Comment: works, what's the difference between each and reduce?

Comment: @AngeloC they're very similar in that they both guarantee order but `reduce` is more general. `reduce` gives each next function the return value of the previous computation where `each` gives each next function the array element itself.

Comment: the doc says:reducer function with the signature (total, current, index, arrayLength), can not understand the use of 'total

Comment: @AngeloC it's like `Array.prototype.reduce` - read about that in MDN - if you have another question about how reduce works you should open another question - answering in comments is really hard :P